# What's the best way to find record with max value of a particular column?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.6

I"m on Mysql 5.6 so window functions aren't available...

I need to get data on a `customerid` level, but since this is on a transactional table, I want just the latest record which is denoted by the highest value of `recordid` (it's an autoincrement field). Think of the grain as this:

```
recordid | customerid | attribute1 | updatetime
```

I was thinking of doing this, but was wondering if there's a better way

```
select
  mytable.customerid,
  attribute1
from mytable
inner join (
  select 
    max(recordid) as maxid,
    customerid
  from mytable) as maxed
  on mytable.recordid = maxed.maxid
```

Comment: You don't need to select customerid in the subquery. You can also do a `WHERE recordid = (SELECT MAX(recordid) FROM mytable)` instead of a join.

Comment: Unless you need to know the row with the max recordid *per customer*, in which case you should join the subquery to the out query on the two columns, maxid and customerid. Anyway, if this is the sort of problem you're trying to solve, follow the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag, there are many answers on Stack Overflow.